# trouble installing ruby 1.9.3-p194

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rvm

I was making some edits to my app on a separate machine, I deployed to production on heroku which caused some errors, and now all of the sudden I am getting a bunch of errors on my main machine.

According to the command line, my issue is that I do not have ruby 1.9.3-p194 installed. I'm not sure what I can do to resolve this issue.

```
$ rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p194
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.7/x86_64/ruby-1.9.3-p194.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary rubies.

Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/glider/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #downloading ruby-1.9.3-p194, this may take a while depending on your connection...
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #extracted to /Users/glider/.rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p194 (already extracted)
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #configuring
Error running 'env LDFLAGS=-L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib CFLAGS=-I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include -L/Users/glider/.rvm/usr/lib ./configure --enable-shared --disable-install-doc --prefix=/Users/glider/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194',
please read /Users/glider/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p194/configure.log
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

Comment: Please make yourself comfortable with the formatting tools, so that you can visually improve your question. I did a single edit to demonstrate it.

Comment: the error tells you to read a file, make a gist of it and include a link.

Comment: Is this related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12878458/rvm-install-ruby-1-9-3-p286-error-running-make-j-9-osx-mountain-lion ?

Answer (score 5):

If you installed rails using railsinstaller.org, there is a bug in /etc/rvmrc.  Open up that file and change the single string where rvm_configure_env is defined into three separate strings.

This is the default code with the bug:

```
rvm_configure_env=('LDFLAGS=-L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib CFLAGS=-I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include  CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include')
```

This is the corrected code:

```
rvm_configure_env=('LDFLAGS=-L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib' 'CFLAGS=-I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include' 'CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include')
```

Comment: Thanks, just had the same problem and this solved it. Quick and simple! :)

Answer (score 0):

It would help to see what other errors you're getting, but I'd also recommend re-installing RVM, per: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12851198/1019369

I recently got a new machine and had a bunch of RVM problems when I brought over all of my data. Uninstalling and re-installing RVM did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem installing ruby 1.9.3 using rvm. I had originally installed ruby and rails using Rails installer. This magic software uses SM framework to manage all native library required by ruby and rails. It does it by modifiying LDFLAGS and CFLAGS.

You can see that from your error running.

I solved this problem by removing SM from OSX

```
rm -rf /opt/sm 
rm /etc/rvmrc
rm /etc/profile.d/sm.sh
```

also remove line from file /etc/profile which sources sm.sh and you tidy all .bashrc, .bash_profile, .zshrc etc..

then try rvm install ruby.. Voila!! works