# Ruby has disappeared. Help me reinstall ruby-1.9.3-p194

Tags: ruby

I'm brand new to Ruby and Ruby on Rails, and am currently going through Michael Hartl's Ruby on Rails tutorial. Or at least I was before trying to load install some open source code led me down a dark journey. I somehow managed to delete any version of Ruby from my computer and RVM won't let me reinstall it using rvm install 1.9.3 (or using the Jewelry Box). I also tried uninstalling Xcode and installing osx-gcc-installer per other instructions I found to no avail.

Added context: running ruby -v makes the system hang.

Here's the error:

```
ruby-1.9.3-p194 - #configuring
Error running 'env LDFLAGS=-L/opt/sm/pkg/active/lib CFLAGS=-I/opt/sm/pkg/active/include    CPATH=/opt/sm/pkg/active/include -L/usr/local/rvm/usr/lib ./configure --enable-shared -- disable-install-doc --prefix=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194', please read  /usr/local/rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p194/configure.log
There has been an error while running configure. Halting the installation.
```

Here's the relevant part of the log:

```
checking build system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.0
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.0
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin12.2.0
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/usr/local/rvm/src/ruby-1.9.3-p194':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
See `config.log' for more details
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

## Reinstall everything!!!

That may sound like a noob one-hit-wonder type of solution. But trust me when I say it will save you time

EDIT:
Things to do is...

1. Install homebrew, if you don't already have it.
2. Implode RVM. This would take down all the rubies and remove RVM
3. If you are on OS X Mountain Lion, run `CC=/Developer/usr/bin/gcc`. This uses good old gcc
4. Reinstall RVM
5. `rvm install 1.9.3`
6. Enjoy (:

Answer (score 1):

If you're on Mac OS X, you might have a much easier time getting Ruby 1.9.3-p194 using [homebrew](https://brew.sh/).

The installation with homebrew installed should be as easy as:

```
$ brew install ruby
```

There are quite a few other resources available to you that are linked specifically by version; Lion, Snow Leopard, Leopard, etc... at [download ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/).

Answer (score 0):

I think you can edit as follows and it will be resolved

https://github.com/railsinstaller/railsinstaller-nix/issues/10

Comment: Please post more than just a URL. URLs tend to disappear, and questions don't. We want to help future users of this site as well.