# rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p286: Error running 'make -j 9' (OSX: Mountain Lion)

Tags: ruby, makefile, rvm

Running `rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p286` gives me this error:

```
Error running 'make -j 9', please read /Users/epeterson/.rvm/log/ruby-1.9.3-p286/make.log
There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This took me forever to hunt down. Was trying different versions of `make`, `gcc`, etc.

It turns out the format of the `rvm_make_flags` environment variable has changed from a string to an array and was not well communicated or documented. This may apply to all rvm_* env variables, not sure.

Check your `~/.rvmrc` and `project/path/.rvmrc`.

```
# before
export rvm_make_flags="-j 9"

# after
export rvm_make_flags=(-j 9)
```

After making this change everything compiled cleanly.

Comment: I am having the same exact issue. I am a command line noob, how would i go about making the fix that you suggest.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty new at this as well. I was not sure about the directions above, but I had a related problem.

What I found is that I just needed to restart Terminal.

I then used `$ type rvm | head -1` and it spit out `rvm is a function`. Which is what you want to get according to the great article found here:

http://www.moncefbelyamani.com/how-to-install-xcode-homebrew-git-rvm-ruby-on-mac/

Answer (score -1):

run `rvm requirements` and it would show all necessary components from RVM to work properly,

on my box, it shows(partial)

```
# For ruby:
brew install autoconf automake apple-gcc42 libtool pkg-config openssl readline libyaml    sqlite libxml2 libxslt libksba
```

so I just run the command, and after than, issue

```
rvm install 1.9.3
```