# Error installing any ruby version with RVM on OSX

Tags: ruby, error-handling, terminal, installation, rvm

Guys I'm about to kill myself with this one!

I had some problems with RVM installing multiple versions of Ruby, and following a thread on Stackoverflow I decided to remove it completely. After reinstalling RVM, I am unable to install any Ruby version at all.

- Mac OS X
- RVM 1.20.10 stable
- Homebrew 0.9.4

Here are some logs:

> rvm install 2.0.0-p0

or:

> rvm install 2.0.0-p195 --autolibs=enabled

```
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/10.8/x86_64/ruby-2.0.0-p0.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Installing requirements for osx, might require sudo password.
Already up-to-date.
Installing required packages: autoconf, automake, libtool, pkg-config, libyaml, readline, libxml2, libxslt, libksba, openssl…
Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_libs_install autoconf automake libtool pkg-config libyaml readline libxml2 libxslt libksba openssl',
please read /Users/admin/.rvm/log/ruby-2.0.0-p0/1368903329_package_install_autoconf_automake_libtool_pkg-config_libyaml_readline_libxml2_libxslt_libksba_openssl.log
```

Logfile reads:

```
[2013-05-18 22:55:29] requirements_osx_brew_libs_install
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/autoconf
There were package installation errors, make sure to read the log.
Check Homebrew requirements github.com/mxcl/homebrew/wiki/Installation
```

> brew doctor

```
Your system is ready to brew.
```

> brew cleanup

```
Removing: /Library/Caches/Homebrew/automake-1.13.1.tar.gz…
Error: Permission denied — /Library/Caches/Homebrew/automake-1.13.1.tar.gz
```

> brew reinstall autoconf

```
Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/autoconf
```

Help!

Comment: maybe you can cleanup as root with sudo brew cleanup and then try brew install autoconf ?

Comment: tried that. Brew cleanup went through, but install autoconf gets me to Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/autoconf

Comment: did you run install instead of reinstall ?

Comment: Grammakovs-MacBook-Air:Cellar grammakov$ brew install autoconf
Error: Permission denied - /Library/Caches/Homebrew/Formula/autoconf.brewing
Grammakovs-MacBook-Air:Cellar grammakov$ sudo brew install autoconf
Password:
Error: Cowardly refusing to `sudo brew install'
You can use brew with sudo, but only if the brew executable is owned by root.
However, this is both not recommended and completely unsupported so do so at
your own risk.

Comment: Ok, after hours I managed to install autoconf, extending write permissions of the Library folder. Now however I am stuck again, as rvm install command keeps returning errors

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I ran into the same issue, you need to manually install all the required packages using Brew. For me I had to run the following installs:

```
brew install autoconf
brew install automake
brew install libtool
brew install apple-gcc42
brew install libyaml
brew install libxslt
brew install libksba
brew install openssl
```

You just need to keep running "rvm requirements" and reading the log and installing the packages needed until there are no more errors.

Comment: Had problem with this method, brew unable to create symlink and when I run it with sudo it refuses to run

Comment: @gerrytan I had that issue. I needed to run `sudo brew link autoconf` after I ran `brew install autoconf`. I had to do that for all these packages. I suspect there is something fishy with my permissions, since the linking always fails but `brew` doesn't want you to install using `sudo`.

Comment: Strange, you shouldn't need to do sudo to run brew, since it installs everything in /usr/local. Check out this other post to fix your premissions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9800527/homebrew-install-permissions-issue

Comment: yup, installing missing packages one by one, does the trick :)

Comment: Also worked for me but have to unlink then install pkg-config

Comment: This saved me a bunch of time and fixed all my issues, thank you!

Comment: Thanks! Mine wanted gcc42 instead of apple-gcc42 and I wasn't sure if I could install apple-gcc42 instead. I installed gcc42. It took about 25 minutes and my fan would go full speed occasionally, but eventually it did install.

Answer (score 8):

After installing RVM, You'll want to run

```
rvm requirements
```

to see if anything else is required to install ruby and rails first.

here is the similar question asked [rvm install ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12878458/rvm-install-ruby-1-9-3-p286-error-running-make-j-9-osx-mountain-lion/14995128#14995128)

Answer (score 4):

This solved problem for me

> ```
> sudo chown -R `whoami` /Library/Caches/Homebrew/
> ```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem

```
brew install pkg-config
```

worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I aswell ran into the permission problem. My /usr/local/opt where the packages are linked had permissions root:wheel. I changed permissions by doing

```
sudo chown -R <localuser>:staff /usr/local/opt
```

where of course "localuser" is your local user you used to install brew.

Then aswell I had to run

```
brew reinstall autoconf
```

and so on instead of just "install", since brew always kept on saying the lib already was installed (yet not linked). "reinstall" simply forces a new install of the package. that did the trick for me.

Hope this helps someone with similar problems.

Answer (score 0):

User which is running brew should have write access to This entire directory path

/Library/Caches/Homebrew/Formula

No need to change ownership just write permission. then running rvm works

Answer (score 0):

I was encountering similar issues, particular around the install of openssl098. I came across [this Homebrew issue](https://github.com/Homebrew/homebrew-versions/issues/1150#issuecomment-178901978), tried `rvm get head` as suggested, and now rvm works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

I'd try to install Xcode Command Line Tools before.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
rvm reinstall ruby-2.3.1 --with-openssl-dir=`brew --prefix openssl`
```

[rvm openssl on Mojave](https://github.com/rvm/rvm/issues/4562)