# RVM not installing any Ruby version on MAC os Monterey Version 12.3.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, macos, homebrew, rvm

Description
I am stuck on this for two days. I am unable to install any ruby version using rvm. I tried to uninstall brew and install it again but the issue is still there. Please don't mind i am very new to ruby on rails. thanks for the help.

Here i have attached all the console errors and steps i performed.

Steps to reproduce

```
➜ ~ rvm list known
➜ ~ rvm | head -n 1
Ruby enVironment Manager 1.29.12 (latest) (c) 2009-2020 Michal Papis, Piotr Kuczynski, Wayne E. Seguin
➜ ~ curl -sSL https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable

Downloading https://github.com/rvm/rvm/archive/1.29.12.tar.gz
Downloading https://github.com/rvm/rvm/releases/download/1.29.12/1.29.12.tar.gz.asc
Found PGP signature at: 'https://github.com/rvm/rvm/releases/download/1.29.12/1.29.12.tar.gz.asc',
but no GPG software exists to validate it, skipping.
Upgrading the RVM installation in /Users/macbookpro/.rvm/
RVM PATH line found in /Users/macbookpro/.mkshrc /Users/macbookpro/.profile /Users/macbookpro/.bashrc /Users/macbookpro/.zshrc.
RVM sourcing line found in /Users/macbookpro/.profile /Users/macbookpro/.bash_profile /Users/macbookpro/.zlogin.
Upgrade of RVM in /Users/macbookpro/.rvm/ is complete.

Thanks for installing RVM 
Please consider donating to our open collective to help us maintain RVM.

 Donate: https://opencollective.com/rvm/donate

➜ ~ rvm install "ruby-2.1.10"
Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/12.3/x86_64/ruby-2.1.10.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Installing requirements for osx.
Updating system - please wait
Installing required packages: autoconf, automake, libtool, pkg-config, coreutils, libyaml, libksba, readline, zlib, openssl - please wait
There were package installation errors, make sure to read the log.

Try brew tap --repair and make sure brew doctor looks reasonable.

Check Homebrew requirements https://docs.brew.sh/Installation
Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_libs_install autoconf automake libtool pkg-config coreutils libyaml libksba readline zlib openssl',
please read /Users/macbookpro/.rvm/log/1652608512_ruby-2.1.10/package_install_autoconf_automake_libtool_pkg-config_coreutils_libyaml_libksba_readline_zlib_openssl.log
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
```

I have installed brew correctly.
Installed RVM attached its version above.
Still not installing any ruby.

Expected behavior:
It should work as brew and rvm is showing correct outputs. But when i am installing ruby its just not working.

```
➜ ~ rvm info

system:

system:
uname: "Darwin macbooks-MacBook-Pro.local 21.4.0 Darwin Kernel Version 21.4.0: Fri Mar 18 00:45:05 PDT 2022; root:xnu-8020.101.4~15/RELEASE_X86_64 x86_64"
name: "OSX"
version: "12.3"
architecture: "x86_64"
bash: "/bin/bash => GNU bash, version 3.2.57(1)-release (x86_64-apple-darwin21)"
zsh: "/bin/zsh => zsh 5.8 (x86_64-apple-darwin21.0)"
remote_path: "osx/12.3/x86_64"
xcode: "13.3.1"

rvm:
version: "1.29.12 (latest)"
updated: "12 minutes 29 seconds ago"
path: "/Users/macbookpro/.rvm"
autolibs: "[4] Allow RVM to use package manager if found, install missing dependencies, install package manager (only OS X)."

homes:
gem: "not set"
ruby: "not set"

binaries:
ruby: "/usr/bin/ruby"
irb: "/usr/bin/irb"
gem: "/usr/bin/gem"
rake: "/usr/bin/rake"

environment:
PATH: "/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/Library/Apple/usr/bin:/Users/macbookpro/.rvm/bin"
GEM_HOME: ""
GEM_PATH: ""
MY_RUBY_HOME: ""
IRBRC: ""
RUBYOPT: ""
gemset: ""
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error installing any ruby version with RVM on OSX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16632543/error-installing-any-ruby-version-with-rvm-on-osx)

Comment: I have already tried everything mentioned in that thread. If you want i can show you the outputs of all those steps suggested in that thread as well.

Answer (score 2):

I had problems installing older ruby version with RBENV, not rvm. Solved using

```
RUBY_CFLAGS=-DUSE_FFI_CLOSURE_ALLOC rbenv install 2.5.1
```

I don't know if this approach could be useful with rvm

Comment: So disappointed by this now I am also thinking of uninstalling rvm and try rbenv hopefully that works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like RVM is unable to install old ruby versions. I tried to install latest version updated brew and it installed it !

```
Last login: Tue May 17 00:31:59 on ttys000
➜  ~ rvm get master
Downloading https://get.rvm.io
No GPG software exists to validate rvm-installer, skipping.
Downloading https://github.com/rvm/rvm/archive/master.tar.gz
Upgrading the RVM installation in /Users/macbookpro/.rvm/
    RVM PATH line found in /Users/macbookpro/.mkshrc /Users/macbookpro/.profile /Users/macbookpro/.bashrc /Users/macbookpro/.zshrc.
    RVM sourcing line found in /Users/macbookpro/.profile /Users/macbookpro/.bash_profile /Users/macbookpro/.zlogin.
Upgrade of RVM in /Users/macbookpro/.rvm/ is complete.

Thanks for installing RVM 
Please consider donating to our open collective to help us maintain RVM.

  Donate: https://opencollective.com/rvm/donate


RVM reloaded!
➜  ~ rvm install ruby-3.1

Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/12.3/x86_64/ruby-3.1.2.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Installing requirements for osx.
Updating system - please wait
Failed to update Homebrew, follow instructions at

    https://docs.brew.sh/Common-Issues

and make sure `brew update` works before continuing.
Error running 'requirements_osx_brew_update_system ruby-3.1.2',
please read /Users/macbookpro/.rvm/log/1652730222_ruby-3.1.2/update_system.log
Requirements installation failed with status: 1.
➜  ~ brew update         
Already up-to-date.
➜  ~ rvm install ruby-3.1

Searching for binary rubies, this might take some time.
No binary rubies available for: osx/12.3/x86_64/ruby-3.1.2.
Continuing with compilation. Please read 'rvm help mount' to get more information on binary rubies.
Checking requirements for osx.
Installing requirements for osx.
Updating system - please wait
Installing required packages: autoconf, automake, libtool, pkg-config, coreutils, libyaml, libksba, readline, zlib, openssl@1.1 - please wait
Certificates bundle '/usr/local/etc/openssl@1.1/cert.pem' is already up to date.
Requirements installation successful.
Installing Ruby from source to: /Users/macbookpro/.rvm/rubies/ruby-3.1.2, this may take a while depending on your cpu(s)...
ruby-3.1.2 - #downloading ruby-3.1.2, this may take a while depending on your connection...
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
 88 19.6M   88 17.4M    0     0  29061      0  0:11:47  0:10:29  0:01:18     0
curl: (56) LibreSSL SSL_read: Operation timed out, errno 60
There was an error(56).
Checking fallback: https://ftp.ruby-lang.org/pub/ruby/3.1/ruby-3.1.2.tar.gz
** Resuming transfer from byte position 18292049
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 2208k  100 2208k    0     0   222k      0  0:00:09  0:00:09 --:--:--  338k
ruby-3.1.2 - #extracting ruby-3.1.2 to /Users/macbookpro/.rvm/src/ruby-3.1.2 - please wait
ruby-3.1.2 - #configuring - please wait
ruby-3.1.2 - #post-configuration - please wait
ruby-3.1.2 - #compiling - please wait
ruby-3.1.2 - #installing - please wait
ruby-3.1.2 - #making binaries executable - please wait
Installed rubygems 3.3.7 is newer than 3.0.9 provided with installed ruby, skipping installation, use --force to force installation.
ruby-3.1.2 - #gemset created /Users/macbookpro/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2@global
ruby-3.1.2 - #importing gemset /Users/macbookpro/.rvm/gemsets/global.gems - please wait
ruby-3.1.2 - #generating global wrappers - please wait
ruby-3.1.2 - #gemset created /Users/macbookpro/.rvm/gems/ruby-3.1.2
ruby-3.1.2 - #importing gemsetfile /Users/macbookpro/.rvm/gemsets/default.gems evaluated to empty gem list
ruby-3.1.2 - #generating default wrappers - please wait
ruby-3.1.2 - #adjusting #shebangs for (gem irb erb ri rdoc testrb rake).
Install of ruby-3.1.2 - #complete 
Ruby was built without documentation, to build it run: rvm docs generate-ri
➜  ~
```